# "bin/bash: python: command not found" returned when running docker image

Tags: python, docker

Here is the `docker run` output:

```
hausey@ubuntu:~/niso2-jxj934$ docker run niso2-jxj934
Test version: 15:59, Mar 24th 2020
Question 1: Evaluation of expression.
Command failed: /bin/bash -c "python /bin/jxj934.py  -question 1  -expr \"(ifleq (ifleq -1.11298616747 1.63619642199 (sub -1.11298616747 -1.11298616747) 1.7699684348) (add (exp -0.822479932786) 1.39992604386) (add -1.11298616747 (exp 0.385042309638)) 0.205973267133)\" -n 10 -x \"-0.168958230447 -0.131749160548 0.0971246476126 1.8706205565 -0.464122426299 2.35887369763 -0.375948313434 -0.613901105864 0.411326743135 -0.149276696072\"" Exit status: exited with code 127 stderr: /bin/bash: python: command not found
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM pklehre/niso2020-lab2-msc
ADD jxj934.py /bin
CMD ["-username","jxj934", "-submission", "python /bin/jxj934.py"]
```

Here is check for `python`:

```
hausey@ubuntu:~/niso2-jxj934$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Is that related to the PATH of python?

Comment: You didn't install python in your docker image. You checked `which python` on your machine and not inside your docker container

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually, it is related to the value of `PATH` but, specifically, that image only has `python3`. In other words, looking through the filesystem with

```sh
find / -name -type f "python*"
```

> Look for regular files named "python*" in `/`

There were only `python3` results.

```
...
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.7
...
```

A quick solution is to specify `python3` in your CMD line (`python3 /bin/jxj934.py`). Another is to add a soft link (`ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.8`). The best solution is to solve it using the package manager. Then again, that depends if you're in control of the `Dockerfile` + image.

When you queried `which python`, you did so on your local machine. The container runs in a different filesystem namespace than yours and with a completely different terminal. The container will behave differently than your machine and any such investigations will yield relevant results only when run within the container.

A little unrelated to your question but it might serve you.
`docker run` has a `--entrypoint` option that allows you to override the image's entrypoint. You can ask for bash and explore the container.

```
docker run --it --entrypoint=bash pklehre/niso2020-lab2-msc
```

> Note that `bash` has to be in the $PATH.

Comment: Thanks.That does it.I have tried the first solution and I will explore the ways you mentioned.Thank you very much!